# In this Azure Active Geo-Replication Microsoft article, what does USC stand for?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741328.aspx, diagrams include references to "USC" and "TDS".  I'm guessing that TDS represents a Tabular Data Stream connection, however what does USC stand for, knowing that it's obviously the geo-replication protocol?

Comment: I think it's a typo in the diagram - it's UCS (replication protocol)
[Check this document][1]. But I don't know what does UCS stand for

  [1]: https://www.sqlbits.com/Downloads/492/SQLBits%202014%20-%20FINAL.pdf

Comment: This might be Cisco UCS http://newsroom.cisco.com/release/1458303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a typo and likely refers to using Cisco UCS in the Microsoft Azure data centers to support SQL Server failover clusters.  For example this guide provides details:  http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/servers-unified-computing/ucs-b-series-blade-servers/guide_c07-707705_1.pdf

Located from this set of Cisco whitepapers:  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/servers-unified-computing/ucs-b-series-blade-servers/white-paper-listing.html

Thank you Alexey and plentysmart